# Counting how many departments a given employee is in (mySQL server)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, one-to-many

So I have a database that has Employees, Departments, and a Works relation that's used to link together employees and departments. I want to get how many departments each employee works in, but I'm just at a complete loss for it.

What I've got so far is this:

```
select count(D.name)
from employee E, department D, works W
where E.eid = W.eid and W.did = D.did
```

I know that the problem is that it's just counting all the columns from the entire query instead of just counting the number of departments for the given employee, but I'm kind of lost on how to limit it.

I was under the impression that I could do this in one query, but am I gonna have to use a join?

Comment: And, guess what, you're already using a join... two, in fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query actually does not seem far off, and might even be correct.  However, I would use the *distinct* count of departments here:

```sql
SELECT e.eid, COUNT(DISTINCT d.did) AS cnt
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN works w ON w.eid = e.eid
LEFT JOIN department d ON d.did = w.did
GROUP BY e.eid;
```

The reason we use the distinct count of departments here is because maybe a given employee had work experience in the same department more than once.  Also note that I have rewritten your query to explicit join syntax (with `LEFT JOIN`).  This is the preferred way to write joins versus the version you were using.